# When does string comparison compare references or value?

Tags: vb.net

So, as far as a i know string is a reference type. Yet when doing this

```
    Dim s1 As String = "hello"
    Dim s2 As String = New String(s1)
    MsgBox((s1 = s2).ToString)
```

the result is true, even though they are different references

I have a keyword kind of tagging system going on in my database. It has a shared registry to make sure that all instances of "hello" would be references to the same instance of "hello". Yet it occurred to me that when filtering and such, comparing 2 "hello"s might instead compare the value, not the reference which would perform a lot worse. Is this the case? If so, how would I compare the references instead?

EDIT: Bonus question: What about the .Contains method in collection classes? From what i can see they also use the overriden value comparison. Would i have to create my own method for checking if a collection has a same value string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Is` operator to compare references, i.e. `MsgBox((s1 Is s2).ToString)`, which returns `False` in this case. If you had something like:

```
Dim s1 As String = "hello"
Dim s2 As String = s1
```

Then it would return `True`.

Comment: +1 Exactly - MsgBox((s1 Is s2).ToString) returns false.

Answer (score 0):

[`String` overrides `=` operator to perform string comparison](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#673).

> [`String.Equality` Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> The Equality method defines the operation of the equality operator for the String class. The operator, in turn, calls the static Equals(String, String) method, which performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.